# Value is not submitting in using Rails ajax form

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to store value in db using Rails ajax form but it is not storing anything.Please let me to know where i did the mistake and help me to resolve this issue.

I am explaining my code below.

## users/index.html.ebr:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function() {  
    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    console.log('hello')
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('create'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
    }).success(function(json){
        console.log("success", json);
    });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
</script>
<p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
<p>
    Name : <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %>
</p>
<p>
    Email : <%= f.email_field :email,placeholder:"Enter your email" %>
</p>
<p>
    Content : <%= f.text_field :content,placeholder:"Enter your content" %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.text_field :submit,:onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
</p>
<% end %>

<div id="sdf-puri" style="display:none" >


    </div>
```

## controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user=User.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
    def create
        @user=User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            flash[:notice]="user created"
        end
    end
end
```

## create.js.erb

```
$("#sdf-puri").css("display", "block");
$("#sdf-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'table' ) %>");
$("#sdf-puri").slideDown(350);
```

## create.html.erb

```
<%= render 'table' %>
```

## _table.html.erb

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name :</th>
            <th>Email :</th>
            <th>Content :</th>
        </tr>
        <% @user.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= user.name %></td>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= user.content %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
```

After submit value should display in same index page.Please help me.

Comment: What is the out put of url: $(this).attr('create'); Also why you use ajax request type post? In that case may have cause for authenticity token issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a built in Ajax system, on your form you need to add `remote: true`

```
form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f|
```

This tells rails to submit the form using Ajax under the hood... You don't need all of the script above the form

Your controller already correctly has the line:

```
responds_to js
```

So all you would do is have a create.js file in your views/user folder that handled your return Ajax stuff such as appending or fading etc

Answer (score 0):

you need to add remote: true in form tag